# Preparation of a HCN/NaCN buffer that has a pH of 9.8 and an osmotic pressure of 1.35 atm at 298 K

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, buffer

You are asked to prepare $\pu{2.0 L}$ of a $\ce{HCN/NaCN}$ buffer that has a $\mathrm{pH}$ of $9.8$ and an osmotic pressure of $\pu{1.35 atm}$ at $\pu{298 K}$. What masses of $\ce{HCN}$ and $\ce{NaCN}$ should you use to prepare the buffer? (Assume complete dissociation of $\ce{NaCN}$)

**Here is my work for the problem:**

$$\mathrm{pH} =-\log K_\mathrm{a} + \log \left(\frac{[\ce{CN-}]}{[\ce{HCN}]} \right) $$

$$9. 8= -\log (4.9 \times 10^{-10}) + \log\left(\frac{[\ce{CN-}]}{[\ce{HCN}]} \right)$$

$$\left(\frac{[\ce{CN-}]}{[\ce{HCN}]} \right) = 3.1$$

**Osmotic pressure $= \Pi = cRT$**

$\pu{1.35 atm} = c (\pu{0.0821 L atm mol-1 K-1})(\pu{298 K})$

$c = \pu{0.055 M}$

*I realized that I can easily solve the problem using a system of equation if I knew which compounds/ions contributed to the osmotic pressure. However, I'm unsure of which ones.* **Therefore, my question is, which compounds/ions contribute to the osmotic pressure, and why?**

Thank you, help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would anyone make a buffer with HCN as the conjugate acid? I would be more concerned with the partial pressure of HCN than the osmotic pressure of the solution. It is not a good idea to have a volatile buffer component, especially when the volatile substance is toxic.

Comment: @Karsten Theis this was just a problem I was given  for practice. I do not know why one would make HCN /NACN buffer.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/108783/72973

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_factor

Answer (score 1):

T respect  Karsten Theis' concern about the buffer in reality. However, I'd rather treated this as an hypothetical practice question for learning.

For all  colligative properties (freezing point and vapor pressure depression, boiling point elevation, and osmotic pressure), ionization of solute(s) must be taken into account (recall the dimensionless van't Hoff factor $i$). For example, if the solution in concern is aqueous $\ce{NaCl}$ for osmotic pressure measurements, then $c = [\ce{Na+}] + [\ce{Cl-}]$ in $\Pi = cRT$ equation (assume $\ce{NaCl}$ dissociate 100% in water).

I assumed your calculation is correct for the $\frac{[\ce{CN-}]}{[\ce{HCN}]}$ ratio using Henderson–Hasselbalch equation. Thus, denote $[\ce{CN-}] = a$ and $[\ce{HCN}] = b$:

$$\frac{[\ce{CN-}]}{[\ce{HCN}]}= \frac{a}{b} = 3.1 \ \Rightarrow \ a = 3.1b \ \tag1$$

Assuming ionization of $\ce{HCN}$ is minimal due to the tiny $K_\mathrm{a}$ the particles in the solution are $[\ce{HCN}], [\ce{Na+}],$ and $[\ce{CN-}]$. Thus,

$$c= 2a + b = 2 \times 3.1b + b = 7.2b \tag2$$

$$\Pi = cRT \ \Rightarrow \ c= 7.2b = \frac{\Pi}{RT} = \frac{\pu{1.35 atm}}{\pu{0.0821 L atm mol-1 K-1} \times \pu{298 K}}\\ = \pu{0.0552 mol L-1} \tag3$$

According to the equation $(3)$, the solution can be diluted enough to be considered as ideal solution, hence $\Pi = cRT$ can be used here.  Solving equation $(3)$ for $b$ gives you:

$$ b = \frac{\pu{0.0552 mol L-1}}{7.2} = \pu{7.66 \times 10^{-3} mol L-1} = [\ce{HCN}]$$

Hence,

$$[\ce{Na+}] = [\ce{CN-}] = a = 3.1b = 3.1 \times \pu{7.66 \times 10^{-3} mol L-1} = \pu{2.38 \times 10^{-2} mol L-1}$$

Now you can calculate the masses of each species to prepare $\pu{2.0 L}$ of appropriate buffer.